# Find all a, b, c, d, e, such that a + b + c + d + e = 1000 with no more than 3 loops

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics

**The rule is:**

- `a, b, c, d, e` is an integer from `0` to `1000`, no relation between `a, b, c, d, e` so `a` can equal to `b` or `c`, ...
- can not use more than 3 loops (it can be 3 nested loops or 3 normal loops, or 2 nested loops + 1 normal loop, ...)
- you need to find all the answers for `(a, b, c, d, e)` that is:

```
a + b + c + d + e = 1000
```

- Your answer can be any format: line by line, array, object, ... but it must be clear so anyone can see it.
- Shortest bytes will be win for each language!

For example here is when I used 5 loops to solve this puzzle and it violates the rules:

https://repl.it/repls/BestKnobbyDonateware

Comment: Using no more than 3 loops is a [non-observable requirement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/58563).

Comment: stop assuming features of languages. How is a loop count?

Comment: @Arnauld I am not sure about that, I think any language can do that.

tsh: I updated my question.

Comment: Clearly, this can be done with no loops: Just print the hard-coded numbers.

Comment: @Adám: It is brilliant idea, you rock!

Comment: *Mathematica*:  `IntegerPartitions[1000, {5}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>23</s> 16 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Full program. No loops. Prints a list of quintuplets with two spaces between them. Each quintuplet has the variables separated by single spaces. Requires 0-indexing (`⎕IO←0`) which is default on many systems.

```apl
⍸1E3=⊃∘.+/5⍴⊂⍳1001
```

Since the above code requires more memory than available on TIO, here's exactly the same, but with a + b + c + d + e between 0 and 10 and a sum of 10:

```apl
⍸1E1=⊃∘.+/5⍴⊂⍳11.0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862gv@P@rdYehqaPuoq/lRxww9bX3TR71bHnU1PerdbGioZ/AfqOa/AhgUAAA)

`⍳1001` the **ɩ**ntegers 0…1000

`⊂` enclose to treat as a unit

`5⍴` reshape that to length 5

`∘.+/` reduction by outer-sum (like outer product, but with plus)
<sup>this creates a 5D array with all dimensions being 1000 elements long</sup>

`⊃` disclose (the reduction had to enclose the result to reduce the rank from 1  to 0)

`1E3` 5D Boolean mask where equal to 1000

`⍸` list of **ɩ**ndices where true

Comment: the output has a lot of number how can read it?

Comment: @chaugiang I've rewritten it. It now prints a b c d e with single spaces in between and quintuplets separated by two spaces.

Comment: awesome, it look so much better now!

Comment: @Adám Out of curiosity, is there any reason for the trailing `.0` in the TIO-10 version?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Just to keep the code length identical to the full version.

Comment: @Adám, hi mate, thank you for interested in my question, I am a novice javascript developer, I want to learn some codegolf language, would I started with APL is good idea, I heard it need a special keyboard right?

Comment: @chaugiang Cool! Come on over in  [The APL Orchard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard), and I'll be happy to help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
₄Ý5ãʒO₄Q
```

No loops.. (Well, maybe 1 if you count the filter as a loop I guess.)

Outputs as a list of lists of integers.

[Try it online with `10` instead of `1000`.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/5PBc08OLT03yDwn8/x8A)

**Explanation:**

```python
₄Ý        # Push a list in the range [0,1000]
  5ã      # Create quintuples by repeating the cartesian product 5 times
    ʒ     # Filter this list by:
     O    #  Where the sum
      ₄Q  #  Is equal to 1000
          # (output the result implicitly after the filter)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [VDM-SL](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/overturetool/documentation/master/documentation/VDM10LangMan/VDM10_lang_man.pdf), 57 bytes

```cs
{[a,b,c,d,e]|a,b,c,d,e in set{0,...,1000}&a+b+c+d+e=1000}
```

Set comprehension - 0 loops

Comment: Hi do you know any online editor support it so I can test?

Comment: @chaugiang don't think there is one, you can use overture though which is based off eclipse and should support all platforms if you're really interested. It's worth pointing out that it probably will take several hours to terminate.

Comment: @chaugiang here's a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/d0N8yDH0) for output for 10 instead of 1000